# Create a custom resource form on Sylius (Symfony3) : "Expected scalar, but got array"

Tags: forms, symfony, sylius

I try to create a custom form for my Sylius Resource "article" using the [Sylius doc](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/forms.html). Without creating custom form, everything works well, but if I want to make a custom form, I have this error `"Invalid type for path "sylius_resource.resources.blog.article.classes.form". Expected scalar, but got array."`

Here is my ArticleType class :

```
<?php

namespace BlogAdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType;

class ArticleType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Build your custom form!
        $builder->add('id', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('titre', TextType::class)
            ->add('date', DateType::class, array('html5' => true))
            ->add('contenu', CKEditorType::class)
            ->add('tags', TextType::class)
            ->add('resume', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Enregistrer l\'article'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'admin_article';
    }
}
```

And the declaration of my resource :

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        blog.article:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: BlogBundle\Entity\Article
                form:
                    default: BlogAdminBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType
```

Does anyone know what is the problem ?

Thanks everyone !

Comment: If i remove the `default : BlogAdminBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType` and just put `form : BlogAdminBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType`, I haven't this error anymore but this one : `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType::__construct()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to register your form as form.type service. And you have to send argument of your form class. You should do something like this:

```
services:
    app.form.type.article:
        class: BlogAdminBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType
        arguments: [BlogBundle\Entity\Article]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

You can check what classes are used for your Article by using this command:
             `php bin/console debug:container | grep article`

Comment: Works well ! Thks !